# UNLOAD query never terminates in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

An UNLOAD query running on Redshift looks to never terminate. I am using Aginity Workbench to run the query. I can see some unloaded files on my S3 bucket though. I wonder how the UNLOAD command works, does it batch unload all the data to S3 at once?

In other words, even though the query does not terminate, can I assume the unload is completed if the files have been moved to S3?

Comment: The connection to the client for such a long-running query can be lost. Did you check the status of the query in the Redshift console?

Comment: Yes, I did. The query was still listed as running.

Comment: Probably you have a huge set of data, but your S3 service is located on a different from Redshift Region. If so you can reduce latency when switch to the common region.